# How to cache png,ico,jpeg

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, png, jpeg, ico

How can I cache the image on my website for 2 days with the htaccess so:

```
1 x 60 x 60 x 24 x 2 = 172800s
```

So I want to cache 'png, jpeg, jpg, ico, js'. How can I do this with the htaccess

Comment: I guess you should use the `Apache` tag instead of `Javascript`. Also, looks like this stuff is bad for you: "You should avoid using .htaccess files completely if you have access to httpd main server config file" -- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `mod_expires` module (based in the MIME type of the file):

```
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A300

# png, jpeg, jpg, ico, js expire after 2 days
ExpiresByType image/gif A172800
ExpiresByType image/png A172800
ExpiresByType image/jpg A172800
ExpiresByType image/x-icon A172800
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A172800
</ifModule>
```

Or the `mod_headers` module (based in file extension):

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
ExpiresActive On

# png, jpeg, jpg, ico, js expire after 2 days
<filesMatch ".(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|ico|js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=172800"
</filesMatch>
</ifModule>
```

This last one gives you more options, like force no-cache, etc.